# How to plot a confidence interval in R

Tags: r, plot, confidence-interval

So I need to graph a confidence interval for a prediction I ran.  I can run the prediction, but when I go to graph the prediction I get a line through all of my data points as opposed to getting the actual confidence interval.

```
GunRate <- seq(0,100, length = 51)

LinearPredictionA <- predict(ModelA, 
    interval = "confidence", 
    newdata = data.frame(ProportionAdultsLivingWithGun = GunRate, 
                         LogMedianIncome = FinalSet$LogMedianIncome, 
                         PctofPeopleinMetro = FinalSet$PctofPeopleinMetro, 
                         PovertyRate = FinalSet$PovertyRate))

##This is my prediction model

plot(x = FinalSet$ProportionAdultsLivingWithGun, 
     y = FinalSet$ViolentCrime1K, 
     col = "red", 
     xlim = c(0, 80), ylim = c(0, 15), 
     xlab ="Proportion of Adults Living With a Gun", 
     ylab = "Violent Crime Rate per 1000", 
     main = "Violent Crime vs. Gun Ownership", 
     sub = "All 50 States & D.C.")

## This plot shows the actual data we used to obtain the prediction


lines(GunRate, LinearPredictionA[, "fit"], type = "l")
lines(GunRate, LinearPredictionA[, "lwr"], lty = "dashed", col = "green")
lines(GunRate, LinearPredictionA[, "upr"], lty = "dashed", col = "green")
```

These line functions are supposed to graph my CI, but instead I get the following graph

[image: plot]

Comment: ??? It sure looks to me like the dashed green lines are your confidence interval

Comment: Yes, but its a line THROUGH all the points on my CI. The black line should be straight and the two green lines should be shaped like a bow

Comment: We don't seem to have the `FinalSet` data from your example.  Nor ModelA   How was Model A generated?

Comment: ModelA is a lm made from FinalSet

Comment: And FinalSet is a data frame made from merging 5 other data frames together. I just cant figure out why I cant draw any kind of fitted line

Comment: Does `ModelA` have more than one predictor variable? If so, then a plot of predictions vs. values of a single predictor variable won't, in general, be a straight line (even if the model has no interactions or higher order predictors), unless you generate predictions with values of all the other predictor variables each fixed at a single value.

Comment: `ModelA` has 5 control variables, but im not trying to predict anything except for `ViolentCrime` based on `GunRate`

Comment: Please show us samples of `LinearPredictionA` and `FinalSet` using `dput()`.

Comment: when I try to include and of the `dput()` summaries they're too long.  but this is the end of `dput(LinearPreictionA) .Dim = c(51L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
    "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
    "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", 
    "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", 
    "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51"
    ), c("fit", "lwr", "upr")))`

Comment: I really just need to know how to draw 3 fitted lines that are the "fit", "upr" and "lwr" of my prediction model `LinearPredictionA`

Comment: How many unique values are there in `FinalSet$LogMedianIncome`. Same question for `FinalSet$PctofPeopleinMetro` and `FinalSet$PovertyRate`.

Comment: All have 51 unique values

Comment: Unless your `newdata` data frame has only one unique value (repeated 51 times) for each predictor variable (except for `ProportionAdultsLivingWithGun`), you will not in general end up with a straight line. To help you further, we need to see a sample of your data. You don't need to paste in the whole thing. Just paste in the output of, for example `dput(LinearPredictionA[1:10, ])`. (Paste it into your question, not into a comment).

Comment: Thank you, that explains my problem.  `LinearPredictionA <- predict(ModelA, interval = "confidence", newdata = data.frame(ProportionAdultsLivingWithGun = GunRate, LogMedianIncome = FinalSet$LogMedianIncome, PctofPeopleinMetro = FinalSet$PctofPeopleinMetro, PovertyRate = FinalSet$PovertyRate))` All of my control variables have the unique values from the actual data, rather than holding them constant to do my prediction

Comment: If anyone comes looking at this later, my FinalSet$xxx variables were mixed.  The answer I got from eipi10 was correct, I just had to into my object and figure out which variables I had misused in my model and then hold all control variables at their mean

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of what's going wrong, using the built-in `mtcars` data frame:

```
# Regression model
m1 = lm(mpg ~ wt + hp + cyl, data=mtcars)
```

Now let's get predictions of `mpg` vs. `wt`, but with 2 different alternating values of `hp` and 3 different alternating values of `cyl`:

```
predData = data.frame(wt=seq(1,5,length=60), hp=rep(c(200,300), 30), cyl=rep(c(4,6,8), 20))
predData = cbind(predData, predict(m1, newdata=predData, interval="confidence"))
```

Note how the prediction jumps around, because `hp` and `cyl` change for each successive value of `wt`:

```
plot(predData$wt, predData$fit, type="l")
lines(predData$wt, predData$lwr, type="l", col="red")
lines(predData$wt, predData$upr, type="l", col="red")
```

[image]

But when we keep `hp` and `cyl` fixed, we get a straight line prediction for `mpg` vs. `wt`:

```
predData2 = data.frame(wt=seq(1,5,length=60), hp=rep(300,60), cyl=rep(6, 60))
predData2 = cbind(predData2, predict(m1, newdata=predData2, interval="confidence"))

plot(predData2$wt, predData2$fit, type="l")
lines(predData2$wt, predData2$lwr, type="l", col="red")
lines(predData2$wt, predData2$upr, type="l", col="red")
```

[image]

Instead of a single line, you can also plot predicted mpg vs. wt lines for several values of another variable. Below is an example where we plot a line for each value of `cyl` that we used to create `predData`. This is easier with `ggplot2` so I've used that package. Using lines for the confidence intervals would make the plot difficult to understand, so I've shown the CI with a fill instead:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(subset(predData, hp==200), aes(wt, fit, fill=factor(cyl), colour=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lwr, max=upr), alpha=0.2, colour=NA) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x="Weight", y="Predicted MPG", colour="Cylinders", fill="Cylinders") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]